# Mysql "Time" type gives an "ArgumentError: argument out of range" in Rails if over 24 hours

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, datetime, time, types

I'm writing a rails application on top of a legacy mysql db which also feeds a PHP production tool. Because of this setup so its not possible for me to change the databases  structure.

The problem I'm having is that two table have a "time" attribute (duration) as long as the time is under 24:00:00 rails handles this, but as soon as rails comes across something like 39:00:34 I get this "ArgumentError: argument out of range".

I've looked into this problem and seen how rails handle the time type, and from my understanding it treats it like a datetime, so a value of 39:00:34 would throw this error.

I need some way of mapping / or changing the type cast so I don't get this error. Reading the value as a string would also be fine.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Rails so there can be a clean, native solution to this, but if all else fails, one workaround might be writing into a VARCHAR field, then running a 2nd query to copy it over into a TIME field within mySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name, stringfield) 
VALUES ("My Record", "999:02:02");

UPDATE tablename SET datefield = CAST(stringfield as TIME) 
WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Although I'm still looking for a solution which does not require writing to this production db.

Comment: Just to let you know I've got round this problem by using Datamapper.

Comment: @Nigel nice! Feel free to flesh that out as an answer of your own for future generations with the same question, and to mark that answer as accepted.