# ActiveRecord returns "argument out of range" for Time of 26:12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord

It seems that ActiveRecord and Ruby's Time object doesn't play nice with times that are over 24:00. However my database has a lot of those, as they represent a time after midnight but considered to be on the same day. This is a design decision of my [data provider](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html#stop_times_txt___Field_Definitions):

> Note: Trips that span multiple dates will have stop times greater than
>   24:00:00. For example, if a trip begins at 10:30:00 p.m. and ends at
>   2:15:00 a.m. on the following day, the stop times would be 22:30:00
>   and 26:15:00. Entering those stop times as 22:30:00 and 02:15:00 would
>   not produce the desired results.

How do I deactivate this "validation" of my Time objects? It was [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076248/mysql-time-type-gives-an-argumenterror-argument-out-of-range-in-rails-if-ov) that I write my time field as a varchar within the MySQL query but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't make the database intervene.

**UPDATE:** Regarding the relevance of keeping the > 24:00 format, querying and asc ordering all the stop_times for a stop using that format would return something like: 23:45, 23:54, 24:35, 24:55, 25:15, which is the actual order in which the next buses are coming.

Whereas going the other way would return: 0:35, 0:55, 1:15, 23:45, 23:54 (this is wrong, the first 3 stop_times are supposed to be sorted *after* the last 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Tilo is right that this is probably not the best time format there is, I had to stick to them and so ended up using raw SQL to convert the time column into a string:

```
sql = "SELECT CONVERT(stop_time, CHAR) as stop_time from stop_times"
stop_times = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all sql
time = stop_times[0]['stop_time'] # => returned as a string
```

Answer (score 2):

the note in your question is talking about a TimeDifference, not a Time object.

I think you should model the TimeDifference as a decimal or float field in the DB, with a value equal to the time difference in numbers of seconds..  and then when you print it out, you can re-format it as Days, Hours, Minutes.

Please note that this is how subtracting Time objects works in Ruby:

```
> t1 = Time.now
 => 2011-11-22 20:54:54 -0800 
> t2 = Time.now.tomorrow
 => 2011-11-23 20:54:59 -0800 
> t2 - t1
 => 86404.928009862    # these are seconds!  just store this in a float or decimal field
> (t2 - t1).class
 => Float              # NOT a Time object
```

Trying to store the time difference in a Time object or Time DB-field seems wrong.

**If you get weird input values from an outside source, like "26:12"** , better to convert them to seconds:

```
hours,minutes = "26:12".split(/:/).map(&:to_i)
seconds = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60
```

... and then store the time-difference in seconds

---

wow, this comes from a Google API?? YIKES!!!

Still, don't store it in a Time object.

you can use divmod() to clean things up:

```
 tomorrow,real_hour = hour.divmod(24)
```

where "tomorrow" stores the number of days in the future, and real_hour is a valid value for a 24-hour clock.

How about making a separate Class "TripTime" for those start and stop times, and have your own attributes: hours, minutes, days ?  Airlines typically show arrival times as "03:12 +1" .. meaning +1 day in the future.

... **or store just those weird values as a string**, that keeps the sort-order, and to calculate the difference in hours/minutes/seconds, you can then convert them as needed as shown above with `split` and `map`

Comment: I think it actually does make sense. Added some info about it to my question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why you say it's talking about a time difference. If I order all the stop_times by departure_time, I would see something like 23:45, 23:54, 24:35, 24:55, 25:15, etc

Comment: Why don't you store the actual Ruby Time object as departure_time and stop_time, and convert this BUGGY input into valid time objects first?

Comment: Because that's how the GTFS feeds are distributed; with > 24:00 time values. I'd like to change as little data as possible...

Comment: Added some additional info on why this Time format makes sense.

Comment: ok, ok, i get it.. that's just an aweful API :P   how about just storing those values in a string?  that keeps the sort-order, and you can calculate the difference in seconds as i mentioned it above..

Comment: That's a possible workaround but again, I'd like to not change the table's data structure at all if possible. `SELECT CONVERT(departure_time, CHAR) as stop_time, stop_name... AS stop_time from stop_times` seems to do the trick. Thanks anyway for the help, I probably should have mentioned right off the bat that I **do not want** to change the data structure.